# SQL Select unique value in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
ID  CatID  Filename
 1    1      abc
 2    2      abc
 3    3      cat
 4    2      dog
 5    1      dog
```

What I want to do is get just 1 ID per filename. I dont mind what ID i get i.e. the first or the last. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you don't care which id you get, then perhaps you shouldn't include id in the query.

Comment: you can up vote and accept an answer at the same time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT MIN(ID), FileName
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FileName
```

Will get you the first ID for each filename

Comment: Technically, it won't necessarily be the first ;-)

Comment: Are you sure this will get the "first" ID from an I/O perspecitve?

Comment: Depends on definition of First - assuming ID is an identity column, it will be the first :)

There is no FIRST() function in SQL Server

Comment: First in sense of first-one-created-assuming-identity-column-auto-assigned-by-sql-server :)

Comment: "assuming ID is an identity column, it will be the first" - Only if your Clustered Index is on your ID, which is often the case, but there are (some) times when it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Russell - that's why I then clarified further in my next comment! 
Definition of the the term "first" is not relevant to this question - getting waaaay too much coverage :D

Comment: putting-dashes-between-every-word-in-a-sentence-makes-it-really-hard-to-read

Sorry for replying when you'd already addressed it, i overlooked your sentence as code, not english :)

Answer (score 3):

```
-- Will get you the min
SELECT MIN(ID), FileName
FROM table
GROUP BY FileName

-- Will get you the max
SELECT MAX(ID), FileName
FROM table
GROUP BY FileName
```

Comment: on my SQL Server 2005 box: _select first(id)_ results in Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'first' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Which DBMS do support 'FIRST()' and 'LAST()' and are these anything other than synonyms for 'MIN()' and 'MAX()' - and if not synonyms, what is the difference between 'FIRST()' and 'MIN()', or between 'LAST()' and 'MAX()'?

Comment: In SQL 2003, FIRST is not an aggregate function; it is a keyword, but it appears in DEPTH FIRST SEARCH and BREADTH FIRST SEARCH and FETCH FIRST and NULLS FIRST.  LAST only appears in the last two contexts.

Comment: FWIW: I went searching on MySQL as a likely place - I found a reference to someone migrating from MS Access confused about the absence of FIRST in MySQL.

Comment: Oracle, MS Access, MySQL implements First() by default for every column in the select that is not Grouped on